# Show that for some $(x_0,y_0)\in\Bbb{R}$, the tangent plane to the graph $z=f(x,y)$ is parallel to $P$ at $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$.

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is $f:W \to\Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function defined on some subset $W \in \Bbb{R}^2$. Let z=ax+by+c be an equation of a plane P in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Suppose that $C=\{(x,y)\in W \mid f(x,y)=ax+by+c\}$ is a simple closed curve in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and that $f$ is defined and differentiable on the open region $R$ bounded by $C$.

I cannot understand this question and cannot imagine what this graph will look like. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Denote $g(x,y) = f(x,y)-(ax+by+c)$, so that $C = \{ g=0 \}$. Then $g$ attains its maximum at some point $(x,y) \in R$ and at this point $\nabla g(x,y) = 0$. This translates to the claim: the tangent plane to the graph of $f$ at $(x,y,f(x,y))$ is parallel to $P$.